# How do i use mysql to get first day of Last 3 months?

Tags: php, mysql

How do i use mysql to get first day of previous 3 months ?

I tried with following mysql query

```
`SELECT concat(date_format(LAST_DAY(now() - INTERVAL 90 DAY),'%Y-%m-'),'01')`
```

which gives `2012-11-01`...Here i need 2013-02-01,2013-01-01,2012-12-01 as date. Here 90 day will be change.Based on interval day how do i get number of previous first day of month

kindly advice

Comment: This might be simpler to figure out on the server side before hitting mysql.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT 
   concat(date_format(LAST_DAY(now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH),'%Y-%m-'),'01') AS day1,
   concat(date_format(LAST_DAY(now() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH),'%Y-%m-'),'01') AS day2,
   concat(date_format(LAST_DAY(now() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH),'%Y-%m-'),'01') AS day3
```

Comment: thanks, here how do we make query with out writing these day1...days will be dynamic so i cannot use this.for example if it 180 days then i have to find last 6 months  first day

Comment: If you use PHP you could write it into a for loop. But that seems to be another question, ain't it?